# I want to make a table like this. But i am unable to do the specific table

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{lSSSSSS}
\toprule
    \multirow{3}{0.3cm}{} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{Baripada } &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{Jagatsinghpur} \\
\hline
 & {Absolute Frequency } & {Frequency(\%)} & {Cumulative Frequency} & {Absolute Frequency} & {Frequency(\%)} & {Cumulative Frequency} \\
      \midrule
   Recently  & 0&   0.00&   0   &6& 3.33&   6 \\
  More than 5 years & 3&    1.67&   3   &47&    26.11   &53\\
  Less than 10 years & 47&  26.11   &50&    14  &7.78&  67 \\
 More than 10 years & 58&   32.22&  108&    20  &11.11& 87 \\
 Since the party formed & 72&   40.00&  180&    93& 51.67&  180 \\\hline
Toatal& 180&100&*&180&100&*\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What is the specific table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: You have the word Frequency in every column. Get it out to save space.

Comment: any news? now you have two examples of your table ...

Answer (score 7):

- your table is too wide to fit in the text area of your page
- you have two possibilities:

  - use abbreviations for column heads and write their meaning as table notes below the table (for this is easily done with the `threeparttable` package)
  - make the text area wider (by using the `geometry` package) and write the column headers in two lines (using the `\thead` macro from the package `makecell`)
- first case:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \begin{table}
      \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{threeparttable}[htb]
      \caption{My table}
       \label{tab:mytable}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                               l
                          *{2}{S[table-format=3.0]
                               S[table-format=3.2]
                               S[table-format=3.0]}
                              }
      \toprule
      &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Baripada}
          &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Jagatsinghpur}                       \\
      \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}
      & {AF\tnote{a}}
          & {F\tnote{b} (\%)}
              & {CF\tnote{c}}
                  & {AF\tnote{a}}
                      & {F\tnote{b} (\%)}
                          & {CF\tnote{c}}                             \\
        \midrule
  Recently                &   0 &   0.00 &   0 &   6 &  3.33  &  6    \\
  More than 5 years       &   3 &   1.67 &   3 &  47 &  26.11 &  53   \\
  Less than 10 years      &  47 &  26.11 &  50 &  14 &   7.78 &  67   \\
  More than 10 years      &  58 &  32.22 & 108 &  20 &  11.11 &  87   \\
  Since the party formed  &  72 &  40.00 & 180 &  93 &  51.67 & 180   \\
      \midrule
  Toatal                  & 180 & 100    &  *  & 180 & 100    & *     \\
      \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
      \end{tabular*}
      \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
      \item[a]    Absolute Frequency
      \item[b]    Frequency
      \item[c]    Cumulative Frequency
      \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
      \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

- second case

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{geometry}

  \usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
  \renewcommand\theadgape{}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{table}
      \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                               l
                          *{2}{S[table-format=3.0]
                               S[table-format=3.2]
                               S[table-format=3.0]}
                              }
      \toprule
      &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Baripada}
          &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Jagatsinghpur}                       \\
      \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}
      & {\thead{Absolute\\ Frequency}}
          & {\thead{Frequency\\ (\%)}}
              & {\thead{Cumulative\\ Frequency}}
                  & {\thead{Absolute\\ Frequency}}
                      & {\thead{Frequency\\ (\%)}}
                          & {\thead{Cumulative\\ Frequency}}          \\
        \midrule
  Recently                &   0 &   0.00 &   0 &   6 &  3.33  &  6    \\
  More than 5 years       &   3 &   1.67 &   3 &  47 &  26.11 &  53   \\
  Less than 10 years      &  47 &  26.11 &  50 &  14 &   7.78 &  67   \\
  More than 10 years      &  58 &  32.22 & 108 &  20 &  11.11 &  87   \\
  Since the party formed  &  72 &  40.00 & 180 &  93 &  51.67 & 180   \\
      \midrule
  Toatal                  & 180 & 100    &  *  & 180 & 100    & *     \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
      \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: @Andrew Swann, thank you for corrections of answer!

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot.